# create an XML document matching Exchange WebDAV output

Tags: c#, xml, email, webdav

I am upgrading an application that gets emails off an Exchange 2003 box using WebDAV. The new Exchange server will be Exchange 2010 SP2 so I have (with a lot of help from So and other places) built code that uses EWS to retriev a list of emails and save the attachments on disc.

The current procedure reads all the emails using WebDAV, and returns an XML doc to the calling procedure ...

Would I be better off changing it to return a list and modifying all the code that follows, or creating an xml doc with the information on it, and what schema should I use?

here is the current code:

```
HttpWebRequest loRequest = default(HttpWebRequest);
HttpWebResponse loResponse = default(HttpWebResponse);
string lsRootUri = null;
string lsQuery = null;
byte[] laBytes = null;

Stream loRequestStream = default(Stream);
Stream loResponseStream = default(Stream);
XmlDocument loXmlDoc = default(XmlDocument);
loXmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

try
    {
    lsRootUri = strServer + "/Exchange/" + strAlias + "/" + strInboxURL;
    lsQuery = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>"
        + "<D:searchrequest xmlns:D = \"DAV:\" xmlns:m=\"urn:schemas:httpmail:\">"
        + "<D:sql>SELECT "
        + "\"urn:schemas:httpmail:to\", "
        + "\"urn:schemas:httpmail:displayto\", "
        + "\"urn:schemas:httpmail:from\", "
        + "\"urn:schemas:httpmail:fromemail\", "
        + "\"urn:schemas:httpmail:subject\", "
        + "\"urn:schemas:httpmail:textdescription\", "
        //+ "\"urn:schemas:httpmail:htmldescription\", "
        + "\"urn:schemas:httpmail:hasattachment\", "
        + "\"urn:schemas:httpmail:attachmentfilename\", "
        + "\"urn:schemas:httpmail:senderemail\", "
        + "\"urn:schemas:httpmail:sendername\", "
        + "\"DAV:displayname\", "
        + "\"urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived\", "
        + "\"urn:schemas:httpmail:read\", "
        + "\"DAV:id\" "
        + "FROM \"" + lsRootUri
        + "\" WHERE \"DAV:ishidden\" = false "
        + "AND \"DAV:isfolder\" = false "
        + "AND \"urn:schemas:httpmail:read\" = false "
        + "AND \"urn:schemas:httpmail:fromemail\" != 'email2case@bankofcyprus.co.uk' "
        + "</D:sql></D:searchrequest>";
        loRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(lsRootUri);
        loRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(strUserName, strPassword);
        loRequest.Method = "SEARCH";
        laBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(lsQuery);
        loRequest.ContentLength = laBytes.Length;
        loRequestStream = loRequest.GetRequestStream();
        loRequestStream.Write(laBytes, 0, laBytes.Length);
        loRequestStream.Close();
        loRequest.ContentType = "text/xml";
        loRequest.Headers.Add("Translate", "F");
        loResponse = (HttpWebResponse)loRequest.GetResponse();
        loResponseStream = loResponse.GetResponseStream();
        loXmlDoc.Load(loResponseStream);
        loResponseStream.Close();
        }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logBuilder("common : Class --> GetUnreadMailAll <--", "Exception", "", ex.Message, "Exception");
        exceptionEmail("An unexpected error has occurred: " + ex.Message, "GetUnreadMailAll", ex.StackTrace, "");
            }
    return loXmlDoc;
    }
```

so what's the best way to create an xml doc in memory that will match the output from the WebDAV, or should I just return a list or collection from the sub to handle the emails and attachments?